# Recurring order option on regular products using Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, rules, feeds, commerce

I have a Drupal site that requires Drupal Commerce and the Commerce Recurring Framework (if I need to switch to UC, so be it). I have come up with a few options but due to vague documentation regarding CRF, I have more questions than answers. I will be uploading a product list using Commerce Feeds -- a CSV with a list of products and their attributes.

One of the options want to provide to customers is the ability to choose whether to automatically re-order products after 1, 3, or 6 months -- or just purchase the product once. Thus, the final order will be a mixture of line items referencing recurring products and regular line items. We need to split off the line items that reference recurring products and create a new master recurring order based off of that. I have come up with two options, but due to limitations in my knowledge of Drupal, I'm not sure if they are possible or how I can find out. These are the options that I've come up with:

- Dynamically adding a "recurring" attribute to a line item/product using the value of a select list [1,3,6] that will cue Commerce Recurring Framework to see a "Recurring Product Type" item. I feel as though this would come through the Rules framework, but I'm not sure when I could interject this information or onto what node.
- Dynamically creating a set of "Recurring Product Type" products based off of the products uploaded in the CSV. That is, for each product in the list, creating one regular product and three recurring products for 7, 14, and 21 that would reference the same information. Selecting from the dropdown would then actually reference different products. I feel as though this would be less desirable since there would be different SKU's, making stock control a little more complex.

If you have past experience or any idea of how to handle this situation, your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue and trying to find my way around. Here is my question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161045/drupal-commerce-toggle-recurring-payment-at-checkout